# Getting a list of users on a network domain

Tags: vb.net, dns

I want to get back to get a list of users on a network domain using VB.Net.

I will have the domain name available to me for use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It might throw an error in the select query.

Please check this:

Did you add a reference to the System.Management assembly to your project? If you haven't, do this:

In VS, click on Project menu > add reference.
On the .Net tab, scroll down until you see System.Management. Click on it to select, then click OK.
Now back in your code, at the very top of your class, put in "Imports System.Management", and you should be all set.

Source:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=560422

It worked for me without any issues. I am able to get all user names for the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might point you in the right direction, using System.DirectoryServices and System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory:

```
Private Function GetDomainUsers(ByVal domainDirectoryEntry As DirectoryEntry, ByRef userList As IList) As Integer
Try
    userList = New ArrayList()

    Using domainDirectoryEntry
        Dim ds As New DirectorySearcher(domainDirectoryEntry, "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))", New String() {"distinguishedName"})

        Using src As SearchResultCollection = ds.FindAll()
            For Each sr As SearchResult In src
                userList.Add(sr.Properties("distinguishedName")(0))
            Next
        End Using
    End Using

    Return userList.Count
Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
    userList = Nothing
    Return -1
Finally
    domainDirectoryEntry = Nothing
End Try
```

End Function

Comment: I tried that just now and VS does not recognize DirectorEntry as a parameter type.

Comment: I should add that im trying to do this in .net 2.0

Comment: Have you added an Imports statement for the System.DirectoryServices namespace in your code, and added a reference to the System.DirectoryServices.dll to your project?

Comment: It is available in .NET 2.0 by the way

Comment: Im a pretty novice programmer. The documentation I found on MSDN is pretty shoddy. Any better direction? What i would like best would be to get a list of users on a domain (which i have the name of) and from a group on that domain (which i have as well)

Answer (score 1):

```
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Management.Instrumentation  

Sub PrintDomainUsers()  

        Dim domainName As String = System.Environment.UserDomainName.ToString
        Dim userQuery As SelectQuery = New SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount", "Domain='" & domainName & "'")
        Try
            Dim userSearch As ManagementObjectSearcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher(userQuery)
            For Each domainUser In userSearch.Get
                Console.WriteLine(domainUser("Name"))
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try

End Sub
```

This works but how do i filter by a certain group. Im getting THOUSANDS of resutls

Comment: I know that I need to add to the condition statement but I do not know what to add. HELP!?!?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be exploring [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) and [System.Management.Instrumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.instrumentation.aspx).Here is a short snippet of how you pull the users of a particular domain using these namespaces.

```
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Management.Instrumentation  

Sub PrintDomainUsers()  

        Dim domainName As String = System.Environment.UserDomainName.ToString
        Dim userQuery As SelectQuery = New SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount", "Domain='" & domainName & "'")
        Try
            Dim userSearch As ManagementObjectSearcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher(userQuery)
            For Each domainUser In userSearch.Get
                Console.WriteLine(domainUser("Name"))
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `System.DirectoryServices` over WMI for Active Directory any day. The strong typing is only one major gain for using the managed classes.